# How to map navigation property collection with Automapper and DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper, navigation-properties

I am using Automapper in MVC Core to map between my entities and DTOs and am injecting it via the following code.

```
 var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
            mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
        });

        IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

I have a relationship like so.

```
public class ProgramDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<AnalystDTO> Analysts { get; set; }
}

public class AnalystDTO
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class ProgramEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AnalystEntity> AnalystEntitys { get; set; }
}

public class AnalystEntity
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int ProgramEntityId { get; set; }
    public ProgramEntity ProgramEntity { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to map between ProgramDTO and ProgramEntity to populate the list of analysts but cannot seem to find a concrete example. My mapping profile currently looks like this.

```
  // Program Analyst
  CreateMap<AnalystDTO, AnalystEntity>();

  CreateMap<AnalystEntity, AnalystDTO>();

  // Program
  CreateMap<ProgramDTO, ProgramEntity>();            

  CreateMap<ProgramEntity, ProgramDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Analysts, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AnalystEntity>, IEnumerable<AnalystDTO>>(s.AnalystEntitys)));
```

This mapping seems to be logically correct, however, upon running the code i receive the error "Mapper not initialized" which I am assuming is because I am using DI.

Is this the correct approach for mapping navigation properties to their own DTOs and, if so, how do I get a reference to Mapper in the mapping profile? If not, can somebody point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Auto Mapper in Core you could leverage the following package to register IMapper with the service collection:

```
AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
```

And then just use it like:

```
services.AddAutoMapper()
```

And this will sniff through the assemblies and load your profile (any class that implements Profile class) and add it to type registrations